# Go exec.Command can't seem to pipe or append information to a .txt file. Is my syntax wrong?

Tags: bash, go, exec

I've been trying to run a command to not have to use a bash script and instead use go for running commands.
HOME=/home/gogopowerrangers
on ubuntu 18.04

```
const systemInfoLoc string = "$HOME/systemvar.txt"

//I've tried to run with full path as well here
getSystemKernel := exec.Command("uname", "-s", ">>", "home/username/system.txt")
getSystemKernel.Run()
//^doesn't seem to return anything

//or
getsystemvar,_ = exec.Command("echo", "$USER", ">", "$HOME/systemvar.txt").Output
fmt.Println(string(getsystemvar))
//here even after the system doesn't seen to recognize $USER or $HOME or actually get the variables
```

Is my syntax wrong? I could pass in the arguments as args []string, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
I know if i write in these into CMD line they work or in a bash script.
Please let me know if you see something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirection is a facility of the shell. If you want to use indirection, you have one of two choices:

- Run it via shell.

  ```
  getSystemKernel := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "uname -s >> home/username/system.txt")
  ```
- Use the `os/exec` package, and process the output stream of the programs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`exec.Command()` doesn't run inside a shell, it just runs the command. What this means for you is that it *won't* expand environment variables (`$HOME`) or do redirection (`>`, `>>`), as that's the shell's job.

I wouldn't recommend running the shell inside `exec.Command()` unless absolutely necessarily, as the required quoting of untrusted input can be tricky and has a high potential for bugs (including security problems).

You can use [`os.ExpandEnv()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ExpandEnv) or `os.GetEnv()` to load the environment variables. You can do redirection by reading the output and then writing it to the desired file, using e.g. [`ioutil.WriteFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile).

Putting that together would look something like (untested):

```
// Expand the $HOME variable.
systemInfoLoc := os.ExpandEnv("$HOME/systemvar.txt")

// Run uname command and get both stdout and stderr
getSystemKernel, err := exec.Command("uname", "-s").CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    // Show error and output
    log.Fatalf("%s: %s", err, getSystemKernel)
}

// Write result to file
err = ioutil.WriteFile("home/username/system.txt", getSystemKernel, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was wondering since I'm not actually passing the command to the bash. If I were to use go build on my go file would this way work with other GOOS other than linux? Also would me building the .go file with bash command passing would it work as well? sorry I'm new to Go.

Comment: @ak97 Yes, this method should be considerably *more* portable than using `bash -c` suggested in the other answers.